# onclick in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery with PHP, like this:

```
<th bgcolor="#FFCC00" align="center">
    <a href="" title="Sort" name="fname" id="fname" >First Name</a>&nbsp;
    <?php if($_REQUEST['o']=="fn"){ ?><img border="0"  id="b1" /><?php } ?>
</th>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#fname').click(function() {
    alert ("come");
    <?php if ($_REQUEST['o'] == "fn") { $_SESSION['clicked'] = "fn"; } ?>
    window.location = '<?php echo $redirect ?>Clients.php?o=fn';
return false;
```

But it doesn't work. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you want the code to do? What error or undesired behaviour do you get with your current code? You understand that PHP code executes on the webserver _before_ the page gets to the browser, while JavaScript (including jQuery) executes in the browser? This means you can't (directly) execute PHP code from JavaScript/jQuery. (If you use View Source in your browser you can see the code the browser received after the PHP code ran on your server. This might make it clearer what's really happening.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use PHP inside of JavaScript, not the way you are trying to.

All PHP code is evaluated server-side - while the page is being generated.
Not while jQuery is processing some callback.

This line will not work:

```
<?php if($_REQUEST['o']=="fn"){$_SESSION['clicked']="fn";}?>
```

If you clarify what you want your AJAX to do, we can help you make it do that.

Comment: iam using same code for another project in local host it will works but change the server  it does not work

Comment: Whether it works or not (I can't see how) it's all wrong to mix server side and javascript like that. As x10 suggests you can use `$.ajax()` to handle interaction between PHP and JS.

Comment: @x10 That line of code will work, the problem is it will run on every page load, not on the click of the `#fname` element as the OP desires. AJAX is the answer here.

Comment: Precisely. I meant "it will not work the way you think it will".